# Why we need to create another variable to work with dummy node in LinkedList

Tags: python, linked-list

I have a Linked List called **list1** = [1,2,4]. I tried to copy it to a new Linked List call **dummy**.

```
        dummy = ListNode()
        while list1:
            dummy.next = list1
            list1 = list1.next
            dummy = dummy.next
        return dummy
```

and

```
        dummy = ListNode()
        head = dummy
        while list1:
            head.next = list1
            list1 = list1.next
            head = head.next
        return dummy.next
```

In the first approach, the output is only [4], but in the second approach when I create another variable called **head** and assigned it equal to dummy then the output is correct [1,2,4]. Can someone help me to explain why we need a variable called **head** in order to make it to work?

Answer (score 0):

`ListNode` is probably a class that has been defined something like the following:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
```

I believe you can solve the problem very easily like this:

```
dummy=list1
return dummy
```

In your first snippet of code, you initialize dummy = ListNode(), leave the first node to have a null value, then move into your while loop and. At every node in dummy after the first node, you are setting the next node to be the entire Linked List `list1`.

In your second snippet of code, you are using `head` as a pointer. That means that `dummy` continues to point to the head of your new linked list, while `head` moves through all the new nodes you are creating. This allows you to keep track of where your new list starts. Singly linked lists only point forwards to the next node, not backwards, so when your pointer reaches the end of the list, it becomes useless.

If you wanted to set each node individually while iterating through the linked list, let the variables list1 and dummy point to the head nodes, and move through the linked list using **pointers** (variables used to keep track of an object's address):

```
    dummy = ListNode()
    pointer1=list1
    pointer2=dummy
    while pointer1:

        pointer2.value = pointer1.value
        pointer2.next = pointer1.next
        pointer1=pointer1.next
        pointer2=pointer2.next
        
    return dummy
```

After `pointer2` and `pointer1` reach the end of the list and become None, they can't point you back to the previous node, because that is the nature of singly linked lists.

Your outputs still seem a bit fishy, if you are defining list1 yourself, please make sure you are properly defining it:

```
list1=ListNode(1)
list1.next=ListNode(2)
list1.next.next=ListNode(4)
```